# How to update another model. Many2one field. Odoo-14

Tags: python, odoo-14

I create data from the account.reconciliation.act model into the direct.statistics model
Then I want to change some data in account.reconciliation.act. and it does not change in the direct.statistics model. I have written a write method with which I would like to update the data in the direct.statistic model.
But it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

I get the error TypeError: write() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
**1.py**

```
class AccountReconciliationAct(models.Model):
    _name = "account.reconciliation.act"
     direct_statistics_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="direct.statistics", string="Direct Statistics")

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
      ....
        else:
            self.env["direct.statistics"].create({
                "direct_advertiser_id": record_id.partner_id.id,
                "direct_payment_net_id": record_id.payment_net_id.id,
                "direct_currency_id": record_id.currency_id.id,
                "direct_last_act_date": record_id.reconciliation_act_date,
                "direct_total_amount": record_id.amount_total,
                "direct_department_ids": record_id.reconciliation_act_line_ids.department_id
            })
        return record_id

    @api.model
    def write(self, values):
        res = super().write(values)
        self.env["direct.statistics"].update({
            "direct_advertiser_id": self.partner_id.id,
            "direct_payment_net_id": self.payment_net_id.id,
            "direct_currency_id": values.get('currency_id.id'),
            "direct_last_act_date": values.get('reconciliation_act_date'),
            "direct_total_amount": values.get('amount_total'),
            "direct_department_ids": values.get('reconciliation_act_line_ids.department_id'),
        })
        return res
```

**2.py**

```
class DirectStatistics(models.Model):
    _name = "direct.statistics"
    _description = "Direct statistics"
    _rec_name = "direct_advertiser_id"

    direct_advertiser_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.partner", string="Advertiser")
    direct_manager_id = fields.Many2one(related="direct_advertiser_id.manager_id", string="Manager")
    direct_payment_net_id = fields.Many2one(related="direct_advertiser_id.payment_net_id", string="Net")
    direct_currency_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.currency", string="Currency")
    direct_conversion_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="affise.conversion", string="Conversions")
    direct_last_act_date = fields.Date(string="Last Act Date", compute="_compute_direct_last_act_date", store=True)
    direct_first_conversion_date = fields.Date(
        string="First Conversion Date", compute="_compute_direct_first_conversion_date", store=True
    )
    direct_department_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name="affise.department", compute="_compute_direct_department_ids", string="Department"
    )
    direct_reconciliation_act_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name="account.reconciliation.act", string="Created Acts", domain=[("state", "!=", "cancel")]
    )

    direct_total_amount = fields.Monetary(
        currency_field="direct_currency_id", string="Total Acts")
```

Comment: Can you override write method  `res = super().write(values)` to `res = super(AccountReconciliationAct, self).write(values)`

Comment: @Nguyen This is not what I want, I need to change the data in the model account.reconciliation.act. and that the values would change in the model direct.statistics

Comment: do you have one `direct.statistics` object per `account.reconciliation.act` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AccountReconciliationAct(models.Model):
    _name = "account.reconciliation.act"

    direct_statistics_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="direct.statistics", string="Direct Statistics")

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
      record_id = super(AccountReconciliationAct, self).create(values)
      ....
        else:
            record_id.direct_statistics_id = self.env["direct.statistics"].create({
                "direct_advertiser_id": record_id.partner_id.id,
                "direct_payment_net_id": record_id.payment_net_id.id,
                "direct_currency_id": record_id.currency_id.id,
                "direct_last_act_date": record_id.reconciliation_act_date,
                "direct_total_amount": record_id.amount_total,
                "direct_department_ids": record_id.reconciliation_act_line_ids.department_id
            })
        return record_id

    def write(self, values):
        res = super(AccountReconciliationAct, self).write(values)
        self.direct_statistics_id.update({
            "direct_advertiser_id": self.partner_id.id,
            "direct_payment_net_id": self.payment_net_id.id,
            "direct_currency_id": values.get('currency_id.id'),
            "direct_last_act_date": values.get('reconciliation_act_date'),
            "direct_total_amount": values.get('amount_total'),
            "direct_department_ids": values.get('reconciliation_act_line_ids.department_id'),
        })
        return res
```

The first thing you need to do is write the created object to `direct_statistics_id` field. This is done so that you can update the value in `write` method. Also don't need to call `@api.model` for write methods.